# Asynchronously waiting for a condition

Tags: java, asynchronous

I would like to wait for a condition asynchronously. Below is an example using `awaitility` library however, as far as I know, `awaitility` is blocking (i.e not async). Any ideas on how to achieve this in an async way natively (or with another lib maybe). Any ideas are appreciated.

```
await().forever().with().pollInterval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .until(() -> redis.eval(lockscript, ScriptOutputType.BOOLEAN, "mutex:" + key).equals(true));
```

```
await().atMost(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).with().pollInterval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(
    () -> redis.eval(lockscript, ScriptOutputType.BOOLEAN, "mutex:" + key).equals(true));
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can take a look at [Completable Futures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), they are asynchronous. You can pass a function to them and `join` or `get` it later.

Comment: @mnestorov looks nice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can play around with [Completable Futures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and a [Scheduled Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to get what you want (or at least something close to that).

We can define a method `until` like so:

```java
public void until(Callable<Boolean> method, long timeout, TimeUnit unit, ScheduledExecutorService s) throws Exception {

    s.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        try {
            Boolean returnVal = method.call();
            if (returnVal == true)
                s.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, timeout, timeout, unit);
}
```

What this does is take a passed `scheduledExecutor` and invoke any `Callable` method (in this case with a return value `Boolean` since this is what you want. This will loop every `timeout` until the requirement is met and the scheduler is shutdown.

**Note:** If you want to re-use the scheduler, **do not** call `shutdown()` on it, but rather `cancel()`.

The way we call this is as follows:

```java
ScheduledExecutorService sched = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
until(() -> basicBoolStatement(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sched);
```

We don't need the scheduler to have more than one thread. Just pass in anything else that returns a boolean for `basicBoolStatement()`.

If you want to give a time limit to your request, then you can do the additional call, like so:

```java
public static void untilAtMost(Callable<Boolean> method, long untilTimeout, long atMostTimeout, TimeUnit unit, ScheduledExecutorService s) throws Exception {

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            until(method, untilTimeout, unit, s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    
    ScheduledExecutorService sched = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    sched.schedule(() -> {
        s.shutdown();
        sched.shutdown();
    }, atMostTimeout, unit);
}
```

Here, we re-use the `until` method above, but we have another scheduler that will `shutdown()` the `until` scheduler when the `atMostTimeout` time passes.

And in the same way, the calling code would look something like:

```java
ScheduledExecutorService sched = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
untilAtMost(() -> basicBoolStatement(), 10, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sched);
```

*Edit:* If you don't want to handle exceptions the way it is with the `Callable` interface, you can use a `Supplier`.

*Disclaimer:* sorry for the messy code, but this is just a proof of concept.